# Why am i able to see the blade in that particular place? Why not in other places?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction

(Please see this [gif](https://9gag.com/gag/awn8MoR) here) The device seems to spin at a very high speed and we can see the wings of the device turning slowly (IDK due to some illusion). We can encounter this phenomenon in spinning fans too.

My question is, why am I able to see the wings of the device on those particular points? Why am I not seeing them in other points? Does the device tend to slow down at those certain points?

I'm not a Physics grad or anything. Sorry if the question is trivial.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/10/opinion/sunday/its-not-a-stream-of-consciousness.html?_r=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a lots of things that go "weird" when you record something with a digital camera. Specifically to your question, you're recognizing the stroboscopic effect ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect)), which happens when you "sample" light with a camera at a specific frame rate. You can see "frozen" motion and even "backwards" motion from different frame rates as shown below:

[image: stroboscopic effect]

Another effect in that clip are the wings changing in size because of [rolling shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter). [Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) is another interesting effect, but not seen in the gif. Have fun exploring!

EDIT:

You can even see this *inside* too, if you have an illumination source that strobes (most things LED, fluorescents sometimes). It will look like this:

[image: hand waving and strobing]

EDIT2:

For continuous light, it appears there are some effects that can be seen with the naked eye. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect#Truly_continuous_illumination

Comment: I agree with your answer that is respective to the device (camera). I can encounter this phenomenon even when I am looking directing at the spinning object. I want to know why is that.

Comment: Updated answer with an explanatory image of strobing inside. Unless you are talking about outside...

Comment: @Bej The only way you can see the wagon wheel effect with the naked eye, in direct sunlight, is because we perceive reality in distinct quanta. Basically our visual system has a frame rate. If vision was continuous, anything spinning fast would just be a blur. I tested it with a spinner and definitely saw the wagon wheel effect.

Answer (score -1):

Vision may seem continuous but it's not. The eye captures a couple of frames per second. If the blade rotates at a rate where every frame has the blade in the same position it looks like the blade isn't moving.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?  I've never seen anything that actually says that vision is taken periodically in any capacity that is similar to frames per second.  I've seen articles discussing how it's increasingly difficult to perceive higher framerates; but nothing that suggest human vision has an upper limit of optical framerate, just  that after a certain frequency there are diminishing returns on the ability to discern the framerate.  The other answer seems to really address it, which explains that the device used to capture the .gif had a framerate; not the human's perception.

Comment: @JMac You're right: there is no defined frame rate for vision: in particular if you look at things like spinning spoked wheels under daylight (so not under any light source which does have a frame rate) you don't get aliasing except in weird cases where you are physically tracking the object with your eyes: you just stop being able to see the thing clearly.

Comment: 10 to 12 images per second https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate

Comment: https://youtu.be/R-IVw8OKjvQ exact same thing. The blades rotation matches the frame rate so they look stationary. You can see the effect in real life by watching the wheels of a car driving next to you. If it's going fast enough the rim appears stationary.

Comment: @zanescheepers Those sources don't really back this up.  We can perceive motion above 10-12 FPS, not images.  In the case of _videos_ for this phenomenon it is recorded and played back on devices with limited frame rates so what is recorded shows the motion in weird ways.  Our eyes don't do it nearly as frequently as recordings.

Comment: @JMac But our eyes do do it, so the same principle applies. The frame rate in humans is however not constant. Adrenaline speeds up the frame rate which is why things appear to happen slower during a traumatic event. Rotate a second hand on a clock at the precise rate and it will appear stationary. That rate is your standard frame rate.

Comment: @zanescheepers I still don't see any actual source for this.  Perception of motion is extremely complicated.  Trying to treat it like digital video may not be justified.

Comment: @JMac a video can not replicate the experiment because it's the frame rate of the video you will perceive. This experiment needs to be done in person. If you have the means, perform the experiment.

Comment: @zanescheepers I've only ever seen it as a transient effect in person.  I've never seen a maintained counter-rotation due to the eye's perceived framerate that I can recall.

Comment: Try looking at the spokes on car tyres as they drive along side you on a freeway. According to your explanation the spokes would become more blurry the faster you go. If I'm right you will have speeds where the spokes seem stationary.

Comment: The phenomena is known as aliasing http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e180/lectures/retina/node12.html

Comment: @zanescheepers That seems to be from how it samples discrete areas, not how it samples discrete times.  It isn't about the "frames per second" but instead about the resolution available to detect motion.

Comment: The rods and cones have a refresher rate. Once a cone absorbs a photon the polarity of the ganglion changes. It needs to return to it's original charge before the cone can absorb another photon. Photons which strike the cone before this change occurs are converted into heat.

Comment: Found it. I knew I'd seen this article somewhere. Enjoy.http://nerdist.com/your-brain-has-a-frame-rate-and-its-pretty-slow/

Comment: @JMac sorry, keep forgetting to put a name.

Comment: @zanescheepers That article (and the one it links to) don't seem to give any sources for the claims that the eye actually perceives motion in frames; just that it will perceive a flickering light as continuous.  It seems anything about "frame rate" is paraphrased off of much more complicated processes that don't work like digital image processing we use now.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/10/opinion/sunday/its-not-a-stream-of-consciousness.html?_r=1 so it's not the eyes, but the brain itself.